# Error when sending html form with POST and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this form:

```
<form id="ereserva"  action="index.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="id">ID</label>
      <input type="id" name="ei" id="eid" readonly class="id text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="en" id="ename"  class="name text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
     </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1">   
</form>
```

Which I am sending using this:

```
$.post("edit.php", $("#ereserva").serialize());
```

to a php file that does this:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$id = $_POST['ei'];        
$name = $_POST['en'];

if($con->query("UPDATE reserves SET nom='".$name."' WHERE ID ='".$id."';")=== TRUE)
         printf("alert('success');");
        else
        printf("alert('fail');");
?>
```

But the console displays a 500 Internal Server error.

I am afraid I made some mistake with names or id, since I have another different form being sent using the same system and it works perfectly.

Still, I am re-reading all the names and ids and I am not finding any problem...

EDIT: To be more explicit, the log says:

```
[Sun May 10 09:13:44.971628 2015] [:error] [pid 6737] [client ::1:49874] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /Library/WebServer/Documents/s$
```

But the variable `id` arrives to POST from the form name `ei`, which is a form field that is definitely populated, so I still don't see it very clearly.

Comment: check your web server error log.

Comment: one error is `, WHERE` in `$con->query("UPDATE reserves SET nom='".$name."', WHERE ID ='".$id."';")` use `$con->query("UPDATE reserves SET nom='".$name."' WHERE ID ='".$id."';")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`500` means there is error on the server:

```
if($con->query("UPDATE reserves SET nom='".$name."' WHERE ID =".$id))
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
    printf("alert('success');");
else
    printf("alert('fail');");
```

You added extra  `comma` in the query before `WHERE`.

Also, guessing `ID` is `integer`, so no need of `quotes`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that, but the error persist. Probably there is something else too. I will try to investigate more

Comment: thanks again @Tushar, I fixed the quotes, although the problem persist. Is as if the `id` wasn't being sent from the form properly

Comment: @telex-wap Try removing `=== TRUE`, this is not necessary, might causing error, not sure.

Comment: At the end, your hint about the quotes made me explore a bit further the query and saw another stray symbol that didn't belong there (I missed it when copying pasting the code here. Once fixed, everything works well!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the error comes from another script, since you're assigning `$_POST['ei']` to `id`, which means `id` IS defined. Should `$_POST['ei']` not be defined, the error would be `undefined index ei`

Also, you should sanitize your data, or use prepared statements to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like this for example:

```
$id = intval($id);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am first understanding how the POST process works, and since I got it working now and the form works well, next step is sanitize the data as you say. This code is not for production, is just a test.